# How do I make my ThreadPool work better with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, multiprocessing

I currently have this function, which does a api call, each api call is requesting different data.  I can do up to 300 concurrent api calls at a time.

Doing this does not seem to go fast, since this is just waiting for the repl I was wondering how I would make this function faster?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import requests

pool = ThreadPool(processes=500)
variables = VariableBaseDict
for item in variables:
    async_result = pool.apply_async(requests.get(url.json()))
    result = async_result.get()
    #do stuff with result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is not actually farming any real work off to a worker thread. You are calling `requests.get(url.json())` right in the main thread, and then passing the object that returns to `pool.apply_async`. You should be doing `pool.apply_async(requests.get, (url.json(),))` instead. That said, even if you corrected this problem, you are then immediately waiting for the reply to the call, which means you never actually run any calls concurrently. You farm one item off to a thread, wait for it to be done, then wait for the next item.

You need to:

1. Fix the issue where you're accidentally calling `requests.get(...)` in the main thread.
2. Either use `pool.map` to farm the list of work off to the worker threads concurrently, or continue using `pool.apply_async`, but instead of immediately calling `async_result.get()`, store all the `async_result` objects in a list, and once you've iterated over `variables`, iterate over the `async_result` list and call `.get()` on each item. That way you actually end up running all the calls concurrently.

So, if you used `apply_async`, you'd do something like this:

```
async_results = [pool.apply_async(requests.get, (build_url(item),)) for item in variables]
for ar in async_results:
    result = ar.get()
    # do stuff with result
```

With `pool.map` it would be:

```
  results = pool.map(requests.get, [build_url(item) for item in variables])
```

Comment: The url does change on every request though, such as extra variables ie "id=3" vs "id=10"

Comment: @nadermx That's fine, in that case you just build your url using `item` (assuming that is what you're building it in reality).

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a Threadpool / the multithreading library rather than using multiprocessing?

Comment: @mayankmehtani You can use the [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) module to get a `ThreadPool` instance while still using the `multiprocessing` API.